# Ajax Request not triggering success, Response 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to request data by ajax from ripe.net, but the ajax request never triggers the success function, even through I get an http Response 200. My current code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.db.ripe.net/search',
    data: {
        'source' : 'ripe',
        'query-string': '172.217.16.67',
        'type-filter': 'inetnum'
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

(I changed the IP to google.com)

Currently I've tried the following things:

- set no headers (I need to set a header with Accept : "application/json" because I need the JSON format
- set the header in beforeSend
- set dataType to json
- set dataType to jsonp (throws an error)
- set dataType to text
- set contentType to "application/json; charset=utf-8"
- add crossDomain: true
- add processData: false

None of the above worked for me. Do you have an idea why the success function isn't called, or what i am doing wrong?

Edit: 
The Requestheaders are:

```
Host: rest.db.ripe.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: ...
Origin: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The Responseheaders are:

```
Date: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 11:15:54 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Content-Length: 1148
Accept-Ranges: none
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Are you getting a  CORS error?

Comment: @Gregor Nope, if I open it by ssl (we have two points to get to the page) I get one, but if its without ssl I get the response, headers a.s.o. I will edit the headers to the question :)

Comment: @Kaddath that will makes no difference as they're effectively the same thing.

Comment: @George I´ve added the headers

Comment: @Kaddath When i add an error function and log all three parameters I get the xhr as object in the first, the message "error" in the second, and nothing in the last

Comment: @Patrick Can you check your console as I'm getting `Failed to load http://rest.db.ripe.net/search?source=ripe&query-string=172.217.16.67&type-filter=inetnum: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5001' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @George jea, I get this error as well when I try to execute the ajax on an ssl protected page. But If I execute it on a page without ssl I just get the word "error" from the error function.

Comment: @Patrick I only get "error" from the function when using it from HTTP too, but I get that error log in the console (outside of the function). If it's the case of CORS there's not much you can do other than contact them directly.

Comment: I think I will try to get the data from the url by another way. RIPE is the organisation for IP's eurasia, I dont asume they will change smth. for me :)
Thanks for the Help and have a good day :)